# Transformar uma função de JavaScript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando passar uma função escrita em javasript para o php,mas acho que errei na tradução de algum comando e não consigo achar o erro.
Função em JavaScript:

```
<script>

    function dec(string)
        {// retorna a matris pura, descompactada
            var myArray = [];
            var str, str2, arr, arr2, lat, lng, f;
            var strings = string.split(" ");
            for(var i=0; i<strings.length; i++)
            {
                str = strings[i];
                str2 = '';
                arr = [];
                arr2 = [];
                for (var j=0; j<str.length; j++)
                {
                    switch (str.charAt(j))
                    {
                        case 'A': str2 += ',0'; break;
                        case 'B': str2 += ',1'; break;
                        case 'C': str2 += ',-1'; break;
                        case 'D': str2 += ',2'; break;
                        case 'E': str2 += ',-2'; break;
                        case 'F': str2 += ',3'; break;
                        case 'G': str2 += ',-3'; break;
                        case 'H': str2 += ',4'; break;
                        case 'I': str2 += ',-4'; break;
                        case 'J': str2 += ',5'; break;
                        case 'K': str2 += ',-5'; break;
                        case 'L': str2 += ',6'; break;
                        case 'M': str2 += ',-6'; break;
                        case 'N': str2 += ',7'; break;
                        case 'O': str2 += ',-7'; break;
                        case 'P': str2 += ',8'; break;
                        case 'Q': str2 += ',-8'; break;
                        case 'R': str2 += ',9'; break;
                        case 'S': str2 += ',-9'; break;
                        default: str2 += str.charAt(j); break;
                    }
                }
                arr = str2.split(",");
                f = arr.shift();
                lng = parseInt(arr[0])/f;
                lat = parseInt(arr[1])/f;
                arr2.push([lat, lng]);
                for (var j=2; j<arr.length; j+=2)

                {
                    lng += parseInt(arr[j])/f;
                    lat += parseInt(arr[j+1])/f;
                    arr2.push([lat, lng]);
                }
                myArray.push(arr2);
            }
            return myArray;
        }
    dec("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");


    </script>
```

Função em PHP:

```
Descompacta('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');
function Descompacta($string){
        $myArray = [];
        $str; 
        $str2; 
        $arr;
        $arr2;
        $lat;
        $lng; 
        $f;
        $strings = split(" ",$string);
        for($i=0; $i<count($strings); $i++)
        {
            $str = $strings[$i];
            $str2 = '';
            $arr = [];
            $arr2 = [];
            for ($j=0; $j<strlen($str); $j++)
            {
                switch (substr($str,$j))
                {
                    case 'A': $str2 += ',0'; break;
                    case 'B': $str2 += ',1'; break;
                    case 'C': $str2 += ',-1'; break;
                    case 'D': $str2 += ',2'; break;
                    case 'E': $str2 += ',-2'; break;
                    case 'F': $str2 += ',3'; break;
                    case 'G': $str2 += ',-3'; break;
                    case 'H': $str2 += ',4'; break;
                    case 'I': $str2 += ',-4'; break;
                    case 'J': $str2 += ',5'; break;
                    case 'K': $str2 += ',-5'; break;
                    case 'L': $str2 += ',6'; break;
                    case 'M': $str2 += ',-6'; break;
                    case 'N': $str2 += ',7'; break;
                    case 'O': $str2 += ',-7'; break;
                    case 'P': $str2 += ',8'; break;
                    case 'Q': $str2 += ',-8'; break;
                    case 'R': $str2 += ',9'; break;
                    case 'S': $str2 += ',-9'; break;
                    default: $str2 += substr($str,$j); break;
                }
            }
            $arr = split(",",$str2);
            $f = array_shift($arr);
            $lng = $arr[0]/$f;
            $lat = $arr[1]/$f;
            array_push($arr2,[$lat, $lng]);

            for ($j=2; $j<count($arr); $j+=2)

            {
                $lng += $arr[$j]/$f;
                $lat += $arr[$j+1]/$f;
                array_push($arr2,[$lat, $lng]);
            }
            array_push($myArray,$arr2);
        }
        }
```

Os erros começam aqui:

```
$arr = split(",",$str2);
```

Alguém percebeu onde está o erro?

Answer (score 3):

## 1º Problema

O problema que indicaste é causado pelo uso da função errada para o efeito desejado.

Se pretendes dividir uma *string* em *array* usando como caractere separador uma virgula, precisas de utilizar a função [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
$arr = explode(",", $str2);
```

A função [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) faz o mesmo que a função [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), mas a forma como operam é diferente:

`explode()` - Divide a *string* em *array* usando uma *string*.

`slit()` - Divide a *string* em *array* usando uma expressão regular.

## 2º Problema

A função [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) do PHP, se não receber os 3 parâmetros não vai devolver apenas um caractere como pretendes que aconteça. Onde tens:

```
substr($str,$j) // tudo depois da posição $j
```

Tens que colocar:

```
substr($str, $j, 1) // um caractere após a posição $j
```

## 3º Problema

A concatenação em PHP é realizada com o caractere `.`, no teu `switch()` está a utilizar o caractere `+`, ou seja, onde tens:

```
switch (substr($str,$j)) {
  case 'A': $str2 += ',0'; break;
  case 'B': $str2 += ',1'; break;
  case 'C': $str2 += ',-1'; break;
  case 'D': $str2 += ',2'; break;
  case 'E': $str2 += ',-2'; break;
  case 'F': $str2 += ',3'; break;
  case 'G': $str2 += ',-3'; break;
  case 'H': $str2 += ',4'; break;
  case 'I': $str2 += ',-4'; break;
  case 'J': $str2 += ',5'; break;
  case 'K': $str2 += ',-5'; break;
  case 'L': $str2 += ',6'; break;
  case 'M': $str2 += ',-6'; break;
  case 'N': $str2 += ',7'; break;
  case 'O': $str2 += ',-7'; break;
  case 'P': $str2 += ',8'; break;
  case 'Q': $str2 += ',-8'; break;
  case 'R': $str2 += ',9'; break;
  case 'S': $str2 += ',-9'; break;
  default: $str2 += substr($str,$j); break;
}
```

Deverás ter:

```
switch (substr($str, $j, 1)) {
  case 'A': $str2 .= ',0'; break;
  case 'B': $str2 .= ',1'; break;
  case 'C': $str2 .= ',-1'; break;
  case 'D': $str2 .= ',2'; break;
  case 'E': $str2 .= ',-2'; break;
  case 'F': $str2 .= ',3'; break;
  case 'G': $str2 .= ',-3'; break;
  case 'H': $str2 .= ',4'; break;
  case 'I': $str2 .= ',-4'; break;
  case 'J': $str2 .= ',5'; break;
  case 'K': $str2 .= ',-5'; break;
  case 'L': $str2 .= ',6'; break;
  case 'M': $str2 .= ',-6'; break;
  case 'N': $str2 .= ',7'; break;
  case 'O': $str2 .= ',-7'; break;
  case 'P': $str2 .= ',8'; break;
  case 'Q': $str2 .= ',-8'; break;
  case 'R': $str2 .= ',9'; break;
  case 'S': $str2 .= ',-9'; break;
  default: $str2 .= substr($str, $j, 1); break;
}
```

## 4º Problema

A tua função não está a devolver nada, ou seja, a mesma é chamada, realiza o seu trabalho e depois "deita fora" o que esteve a fazer. No final da mesma deverás fazer uso do [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) para devolver a variável `$myArray`:

```
function Descompacta($string) {

  // ...

  return $myArray;
}
```

## 5º Problema

Antes da divisão dos valores para as variáveis `$lng` e `$lat`, em JavaScript, está a ser extraído o valor inteiro para utilizar na divisão. No PHP não estás a agir dessa forma.

Para este efeito, podes fazer uso da função [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) que te vai devolver o valor inteiro de uma variável:

```
$lng = $arr[0]/$f;
$lat = $arr[1]/$f;
```

Vai passar para:

```
$lng = intval($arr[0])/$f;
$lat = intval($arr[1])/$f;
```

---

## [Exemplo no Ideone](http://ideone.com/jQtBpv)

Usei uma *string* de entrada mais pequena porque o Ideone não disponibiliza memória suficiente para executar o *script* com o tamanho da tua *string* original:

```
function Descompacta($string) {

    $myArray = [];
    $str; 
    $str2; 
    $arr;
    $arr2;
    $lat;
    $lng; 
    $f;
    $strings = explode(" ",$string);

    for ($i=0; $i<count($strings); $i++) {

        $str = $strings[$i];
        $str2 = '';
        $arr = [];
        $arr2 = [];

        for ($j=0; $j<strlen($str); $j++) {

            switch (substr($str, $j, 1)) {

                case 'A': $str2 .= ',0';    break;
                case 'B': $str2 .= ',1';    break;
                case 'C': $str2 .= ',-1';   break;
                case 'D': $str2 .= ',2';    break;
                case 'E': $str2 .= ',-2';   break;
                case 'F': $str2 .= ',3';    break;
                case 'G': $str2 .= ',-3';   break;
                case 'H': $str2 .= ',4';    break;
                case 'I': $str2 .= ',-4';   break;
                case 'J': $str2 .= ',5';    break;
                case 'K': $str2 .= ',-5';   break;
                case 'L': $str2 .= ',6';    break;
                case 'M': $str2 .= ',-6';   break;
                case 'N': $str2 .= ',7';    break;
                case 'O': $str2 .= ',-7';   break;
                case 'P': $str2 .= ',8';    break;
                case 'Q': $str2 .= ',-8';   break;
                case 'R': $str2 .= ',9';    break;
                case 'S': $str2 .= ',-9';   break;
                default: $str2 .= substr($str, $j, 1);
            }
        }

        $arr = explode(",", $str2);
        $f = array_shift($arr);
        $lng = intval($arr[0])/$f;
        $lat = intval($arr[1])/$f;
        array_push($arr2,[$lat, $lng]);

        for ($j=2; $j<count($arr); $j+=2) {

            $lng += intval($arr[$j])/$f;
            $lat += intval($arr[$j+1])/$f;
            array_push($arr2,[$lat, $lng]);
        }

        array_push($myArray,$arr2);
    }

    return $myArray;
}

$output = Descompacta('1000I6575E3374BCBAACBABABABABBABBAABBBABBAABBABBDABAABBBABBAABBAABBABAABBBABBAABBBABBBBAABBAACBABCBABAABBABCBAACBCACB');

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: ,entendi,mas eu acho que o erro está quando sai do switchcase pois se eu der print_r no $str2,ele sai como "INF"

Comment: Não foi o que referias na pergunta, não estive a analisar tudo. Mas no teu `switch()` estás a concatenar com `+=` mas em PHP tens que usar [`.=`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) :)

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Estive a rever a função, resolvi mais problemas que encontrei e montei um exemplo no Ideone. Lê a resposta para saberes onde encontrei problemas e porque é que eles aconteceram.

Comment: Parece que você está certo, mas notei que nos exemplos faltou o `intval` (para ser equivalente ao `parseInt`), não? Eu não testei o código e realmente não sei como funciona, mas acredito que isto seja parte da importante.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado, não tinha visto esse detalhe. Não entendi ainda se é requerido ou se já vinha a mais do original em JS, mas está lá :)